# System.TypeLoadException in windows app development

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, ikvm

I am implementing liblinear in windows app using visual studio express 2013 for windows. After installing liblinear using nuget package manager(link is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Liblinear/) I was trying to use it:

```
using de.bwaldvogel.liblinear;
```

And in the code I typed :

```
Parameter para = new Parameter(SolverType.MCSVM_CS, 1.0 , 0.01);
```

but it gives error while running, stating:

```
An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException'occured in FileExplorer.DLL but was not 
handled in the user code.
Additional Information: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Iserializable
' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Also when nuget package is installed there are no errors but there are warnings stating

```
Reference to type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable' claims it is defined in
'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\mscorlib.dll',
but it could not be found   (in IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll)

Reference to type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo' claims it is defined
in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0
\mscorlib.dll', but it could not be found   (in IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll)
```

Could anyone help me out with this? I am developing app for windows phone 8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the ISerializable interface is not available for Windows Phone 8.x. :( Check out the Platforms section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [This thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/system-runtime-serialization-iserializable-doesnt-exist-in-target-framework.216475/) has additional info as well.

Is the liblinear NuGet package supposed to be supported on Windows Phone? If so, I would get in contact with the author of the package directly.

Comment: No, not supported(found out after posting the question). You can try out this for svm on windows phone :https://github.com/cureos/accord.